# Brother printer not printing last page in duplex mode

Tags: linux, printer

Since I upgraded to Mint 18.3 (Ubuntu 16.04), my printer (Brother HL-2250DN, Ethernet-attached) has stopped printing the last page of documents when printing in double-sided mode. It requires that I press the "Go" button to flush the last page.

The same printer appears to work fine when printing from Windows or macOS.

Comment: Have you installed the drivers?

Comment: What drivers? It prints the rest of the document, so ... yes, I guess?

Comment: It may work with support already available at the kernel but Brother publishes Linux drivers for their printers (proprietary, I guess): http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=hl2250dn_eu_as&os=128

Comment: Ah. Cool. No, I'm probably using the default drivers. I'll check it out tomorrow. Thanks.